# The specified object is not indexable

Tags: python, testcomplete

From the example given on smartbear's official website,

```
# The following routine checks the width and height attributes of
# IMG elements located on a web page.

def Test():
    # Obtains the page object
    url = "****";
    Browsers.Item[btChrome].Run(url);
    page = Sys.Browser("*").Page("*");

    # Obtains the page's images
    images = page.contentDocument.images;
    Log.Message(images.length)

    for img in images:    # <<<<<<<This is the error
        # other calculating stuff
```

When I executed this code snippet in testcomplete, I got an error,

- **RuntimeError
  The specified object is not indexable.**

`Log.Message(images.length)` gives me a result of 9, which is expected.

I also attempted to get the type, `Log.Message(type(images))` gives me a blank output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should at least provide a complete traceback  to get help.

Comment: @Sraw, testcomplete does not provide as much traceback, RuntimeError The specified object is not indexable is all of it.

Comment: @YuZhang maybe you can iterate over it with a list comprehension

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks will take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with this images array as with an indexable collection is not supported at the moment. The sample you refer on the [official website](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/web/general/examples/image-size.html) has different code:

```
for i in range (0, images.length-1):
```

Comment: yeah, I tried this one, did not work either. I modified then posted my code. It is so strange that they claimed that it should work but unsupported in fact.

Comment: Hm. Support of this functionality never was claimed. I think you are confused with another script example.